# $||\cdot||_p$ of the principal components of matrix $M_{n \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem:

> Show $||\cdot||_p$ of any principal submatrix $\tilde{M}_{l\times l}$ of matrix $M_{n \times n}$ $(l \le n)$ is less than or equal to $M$, i.e. 
>   $$||\tilde{M}_{l\times l}||_p \le ||M||_p$$

where $||\cdot||_p$ denotes the matrix $p$-norm, which is $||M||_p = \mathrm{sup}_{x \neq 0} \frac{||Ax||_p}{||x||_p}$.

---

### Try

It is direct from induction that it suffices to show for $\tilde{M}_{(n-1)\times (n-l)}$, i.e.

$$||\tilde{M}_{(n-1)\times (n-1)}||_p \le ||M||_p$$

Let $T := \left[I_{n-1} | 0 \right]$, where $0 = [0, \cdots, 0]_{n-1}^\ast$, then

$$
\tilde{M}_{(n-1)\times (n-1)} = TMT^\ast
$$

where $\ast$ denotes the conjugate transpose.

If I assume $||T||_p = ||T^\ast||_p=1$, and using the submultiplicative property of p-norms of matrix,

$$
\begin{align}
||\tilde{M}_{(n-1)\times (n-1)}||_p &= ||TMT^\ast||_p \\
&\le ||T||_p ||M||_p ||T^\ast||_p \\
&= ||M||_p
\end{align}
$$

but I'm stuck at showing

$$
||T||_p = \mathrm{sup}_{||x||_p=1} ||Tx||_p = 1
$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there!  To show that $\|T\|_p \leq 1$, it suffices to note that
$$
\|Tx\|_p = (|x_1|^p + \cdots + |x_{n-1}|^p)^{1/p} \leq 
(|x_1|^p + \cdots + |x_{n-1}|^p + |x_n|^p)^{1/p} = \|x\|_p
$$
To show that $\|T\|_p \geq 1$, it suffices to note that $\|Te_1\|=\|e_1\|=1$, where $e_1$ denotes the first column of the identity matrix.

Comment: Wait.. can you specify on "it suffices to note that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$"? $T$ is not square, but rather $\sigma(T^TT)=\sigma(I)=\{1\}$, which means all the singular values of $T$ is 1. Is this related to $\Vert T \Vert_p \ge 1$?

Comment: @Moreblue I’ve provided a different argument. I’m not sure whether your statement regarding singular values is true.